# In TFS or MTM, is there a way to lock a test case workitem from being edited once it has a test execution record associated to it?

Tags: mtm

In `MTM (or TFS) 2010`, I want to be able to lock a Test Case work item from being modified (description or steps) once it has been executed (has 1 or more execution history records).

I am having problems were testers are linking test cases executed against previous releases to a new release and then modifying the test case, in some cases substantially as the product has changed.

When looking at history, it now appears that this new test was executed and passed successfully on prior releases inappropriately.  What should happen is that a new test case is created (copy from) but I can't seem to enforce that rule within the system.  I need to be able to lock the contents of a test case once its been executed so I always have an accurate historical record of how the product was tested when released.

If we ever had to do a patch to that old version, this old test case would still be accurate, but instead what we have is the test case was modified for new functionality and is not applicable to the original version any more.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The testers should put the test cases in the Closed state after they are executed against a previous release. For new releases they should run only test cases that are in the Ready state.